# Appearance of the name of the author in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using the theme `CambridgeUS` for a `beamer` presentation. I encounter the following problem. Here is my heading.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Title of my talk}
\author{John Smith}
\date{April 12, 2047}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
...

\end{document}
```

Now, LaTeX will print correctly "John Smith" as the name of the author on the first frame. It also appears at the bottom of every frame but then with "( )" after the name. I don't know how to get rid of those parentheses. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Howdy those are the brackets for the short-institute which may be defined as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Title of my talk}
\author{John Smith}
\date{April 12, 2047}
\institute[short]{test}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage }
\end{document}
```

To get rid of those brackets you need to alter the theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{\insertshortinstitute}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{Title of my talk}
\author{John Smith}
\date{April 12, 2047}
\institute[short]{test}
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

This is exactly the definition as found in `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` (which is used by `CambridgeUS`) minus the brackets. (If you don't want to display an institute just leave it blank)

### Update 12/2012

There has been an update which automatically checks if `\institute` is used or not. So with newer beamer versions, there should be no brackets at all, as long nowhere `\institute` is called. Checked with version 3.24 A of the  `beamer` class.

Answer (score 6):

They are needed when you insert the name of the institute by means of `\institute{}`.

To get rid of them you can customize the `infolines footline`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Title of my talk}
\author{John Smith}
\date{April 12, 2047}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}

\begin{frame}{Hello First A}
hello
\end{frame}
```

In this way you get:

[image]