# Beamer: remove brackets in author's institution

Tags: beamer, titles

In a beamer template I caught from the internet, next to the author's name there are brackets. I suppose they were meant for the author's institution. Anyway how can I remove them?
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\usepackage{soul}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black,bg=yellow!85!orange}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\begin{document}
\title{Regras de acentuação}
\author{A. Martins}
\date{\today}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't get any brackets with a simple test, can you turn your code into a complete, compilable, example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In [Appearance of the name of the author in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51665/13304) there's a way to get rid of the brackets when the `\institute` command is not used. You can easily derive how to the same when the `\institute` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets has the *short author name*.

```
\title[Short Title]{Full Title}
\subtitle[Short Subtitle]{Full Subtitle}
\author[Short Author Names]{Full Author Name}
\institute[Short Name Institute]{Full Institute Name}
```

See page 93 of [Beamer Use Guide](http://www.las.ic.unicamp.br/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#93)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\usepackage{soul}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black,bg=yellow!85!orange}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}

\title[Acentuação]{Regras de acentuação}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Anderson]{Anderson Weller}
\institute[Unicamp]{Universidade Estadual de Campinas\\Instituto de Computação}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First level item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Second level item 1
            \item Second level item 2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```